# How to keep sound on remote when using xfreerdp remote desktop connection?

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

I'm using [xfreerdp](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) on my Linux ([Fedora 23](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/)) desktop to make a remote desktop connection to my company-issued windows laptop.  How do I leave the sound enabled on the laptop so that the headset connected to it continues to work for things like Lync meeting?  The default behavior on the laptop is to disable sound for all remote-desktop connections.  There doesn't appear to be any control for this within Windows (Windows 8.1) on the laptop.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `/audio-mode:1` to the end of your `xfreerdp` command line

0 - redirect

1 - leave on server (or laptop)

2 - disable audio

I figured this out by reading [settings.h](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/4592deee724e2be837c5c3439ed78f16f2c797e9/include/freerdp/settings.h).  It worked for me (OpenSUSE to Windows 10 Enterprise).